# PHP Grab URL of Current Site, but from a master file hosted on a server

Tags: php, httprequest

Hey guys basically I have a master file hosted on a server, and what it does is echo a list of links to a bunch of other sites. The set of links it grabs is based on the URL of the current site. The problem I'm having is that using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on a server produces the url of that server and I want it produce the url of the site that my master page is loaded in to

```
<?php
$url = parse_url($_GET['url']); 
$str = $url['host']; 
echo $str; 
if ($str < "g"){ 
    //do stuff 
    echo(" has first character lower than g");
} 
else{ 
     echo(" has not first character lower than g"); 
}

?>
```

Comment: what does have my code to do with this?

Comment: @genesis, your code works and so thats what I'm gonna be using. Now I need it to be able to do this from mulitple websites but with a file thats coming from one server

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the client servers hostname into the `$_GET['url']` then look for it in the `[query]` key outputted by `parse_url($_GET['url']);`

```
<?php 
//client side host
file_get_contents('http://server.site.com/masterfile.php?url='.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
?>
```

If I understand you correctly. :s